# How to use the same android SQLite DB in native code created from cordova?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cordova

I have set up an SQLite DB in my cordova app. Then i need to develop a new plugin which will read this DB. So how do i access the DB created from cordova from my native code?

this is how i created the DB:

```
var shortName = 'mydb1';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'my database';
var mydb = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, 100000000);
```

i have created a table called 'student' and insert some data. everything seems to be working fine. I can even view back the data inserted.

Now i need to develop a plugin using java and the plugin need to read the 'student' table i just created. This is my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb1",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();

return resultSet.getString(0);
```

My code above produced the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: student (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM student
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(no such table: student (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM student)
```

Please help

Additional Info:

- i already checked the package name on my java code and im very sure
  im using the right one
- this is a very old apps which use cordova 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the database path. seems like the database path used by cordova is different. Thus, i need to use the full path of the database. here how i solved it

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/com.my.packagename/app_webview/databases/file__0/1",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

I actually have to root my device to actually found this exact path.